# Infinite cone surface * AABB intersection testing

Tags: 3d, geometry, collision-detection, intersection

I'm trying to discover a faster algorithm for testing whether an axis-aligned [conical surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_surface) intersects the volume of an axis-aligned bounding box.

The current algorithm I developed is as follows:

[image: cone, AABB, lines along 4 parallel edges, and intersection points]

- x = 0
- For each of any 4 parallel edges of the AABB:

  - Intersect its line with the cone.
  - If the intersection point is within the AABB:

    - Return true.
  - If the intersection point is on a specific side of the AABB:

    - x += 1
- If x == 0 or x == 4 (all the intersections were on one side of the AABB):

  - Return false.
- Return true.

Can anyone think of a more efficient one? This seems to do a lot of extra work by computing each line intersection.

EDIT:

Above algorithm is bad, for example:

[image: cone hits untested axis of box]

The cone can intersect only one edge of the box in a way that all the axis-line intersections are on one side, so the above algorithm doesn't work unless all edges are tested or the edges to be tested are intelligently chosen (maybe the edges closest to the cone?).

**EDIT EDIT: See my own answer below for the solution I later discovered, which seems nearly optimal to me.**

Comment: Somewhat obviously, it's often faster to check a bounding sphere (in this case, of the box) first.

Comment: Also - wouldn't it be possible for your algorithm to fail - e.g. if the point of the cone pierced only one face and no box edges intersected?

Comment: Among other reasons (see above), yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a possibly optimal solution:

The equation for a unit right cone opening along the +-z axis is `x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0`.

Find the maximum and minimum of `x^2 + y^2 - z^2` over the AABB using [interval arithmatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic). Hint: For `x^2`, the minimum is `clamp(0, [xmin, xmax])^2` and the maximum is `max(xmin^2, xmax^2)`.

- If the resulting interval is completely negative, the box is completely inside the cone.
- If the resulting interval contains 0, the box intersects the surface of the cone.
- If the resulting interval is completely positive, the box is completely outside of the cone.

Comment: Some optimizations are possible, such as expanding the calculations to do an early escape by only computing the upper or lower limit, and using that to return completely inside or completely outside.





In fact, if only a true/false result is desired, only the calculation of the lower limit is required.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [this table of object/object intersection tests](http://www.realtimerendering.com/intersections.html) it seems that there's no well-known cone/AABB intersection test. So you're on your own, I'm afraid!

You might start with David Eberly's article "[Intersection of a Triangle and a Cone](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionTriangleCone.pdf)" and see how much of that you can adapt to your situation. (In the worst case, an AABB is made up of 12 triangles, but I expect you can do better than that.)

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I referenced your link in my answer. If that's a problem, I'll move it to a comment instead.

Comment: No, go ahead. I couldn't be bothered to do the legwork myself.

Comment: On the referenced site there is an intersection test between cone and oriented bounding box, which indeed relies on a cone-AABB test. Not trivial, but worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

The [link to the David Eberly article](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionTriangleCone.pdf) from @Gareth Rees is a good one, but if you split everything into triangles, you'll end up checking redundant vertices and edges. I think this will work well:

1. (Optional) Check if the AABB is entirely on the opposite side of the plane perpendicular to the cone axis. If so, there's no intersection.
2. Check each of the 8 vertices to see if it's inside the cone. If any vertex is, the cone and AABB intersect. This is pretty straighforward, but it's explained on page 4 of the link.
3. Check each of the 12 edges to see if they intersect the cone. If any edge does, the cone and AABB intersect. This is on pages 4-5 of the link.
4. Check each of the 6 faces to see if they intersect the cone. If any edge does, the cone and AABB intersect. It's sufficient to the check ray formed by the cone axis against the AABB; this is a pretty standard intersection test.

It may actually be better to swap the order the face and edge checks; I'd expect the face checks to be faster that the edge ones, so you might be able to exit earlier.

There are probably some nice opportunities for SIMD optimizations since the numbers of vertices and edges are both multiples of 4 and the cone is axis-aligned, but that's beyond the scope of this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an algorithm to solve the general case of an arbitrary cone and aabb, but it still handles your specific case efficiently.

I described it in another thread:
[Detect if a cube and a cone intersect each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023977/detect-if-a-cube-and-a-cone-intersect-each-other)

Comment: Ah, cool! It seems like yours is still at least an order of magnitude slower than my answer for this specific case, though. My answer takes about 10 floating point operations.

Comment: I also suspect that the technique I presented here (based on interval arithmetic) could be applied to the general case.

Comment: I have since optimized my solution quite a bit. Yours is still faster, but at this point, knowing what I know, it likely means you have missed cases because this is a VERY complex problem. What about the case where the cone is next to the box and the base of the cone ends near the middle of the box? Imagine that the edge of the cone doesn't touch the box until it intersects in the middle at the base of the cone.

Comment: Ah, the title is "infinite" cone, hah. In that case your solution does work quite well. Even so, what I said above proves that your method, taken as is, does not apply to the general case.