# Detect if a cube and a cone intersect each other?

Tags: python, c++, math, 3d, collision-detection

Consider two geometrical objects in 3D:

- a cube aligned with the axes and defined by the position of its center and its extent (edge length)
- a cone not aligned with the axes and defined by the position of its vertex, the position of the center of its base, and the half-angle at the vertex

Here is a small code to define these objects in C++:

```
// Preprocessor
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>

// 3D cube from the position of its center and the side extent
class cube
{ 
    public:
        cube(const std::array<double, 3>& pos, const double ext)
        : _position(pos), _extent(ext) 
        {;}
        double center(const unsigned int idim) 
            {return _position[idim];}
        double min(const unsigned int idim)
            {return _position[idim]-_extent/2;}
        double max(const unsigned int idim)
            {return _position[idim]+_extent/2;}
        double extent()
            {return _extent;}
        double volume()
            {return std::pow(_extent, 3);}
    protected:
        std::array<double, 3> _position;
        double _extent;
};

// 3d cone from the position of its vertex, the base center, and the angle
class cone
{
    public:
        cone(const std::array<double, 3>& vert, 
             const std::array<double, 3>& bas, 
             const double ang)
        : _vertex(vert), _base(bas), _angle(ang)
        {;}
        double vertex(const unsigned int idim)
            {return _vertex[idim];}
        double base(const unsigned int idim)
            {return _base[idim];}
        double angle()
            {return _angle;}
        double height()
            {return std::sqrt(std::pow(_vertex[0]-_base[0], 2)+std::pow(
            _vertex[1]-_base[1], 2)+std::pow(_vertex[2]-_base[2], 2));}
        double radius()
            {return std::tan(_angle)*height();}
        double circle()
            {return 4*std::atan(1)*std::pow(radius(), 2);}
        double volume()
            {return circle()*height()/3;}
    protected:
        std::array<double, 3> _vertex;
        std::array<double, 3> _base;
        double _angle;
};
```

I would like to write a function to detect whether the intersection of a cube and a cone is empty or not:

```
// Detect whether the intersection between a 3d cube and a 3d cone is not null
bool intersection(const cube& x, const cone& y)
{
    // Function that returns false if the intersection of x and y is empty
    // and true otherwise
}
```

Here is an illustration of the problem (the illustration is in 2D, but my problem is in 3D):
[image: Cube and cone intersection]

How to do that efficiently (I am searching for an algorithm, so the answer can be in C, C++ or Python) ?

Note: Here intersection is defined as: it exists a non-null 3D volume that is in the cube and in the cone (if the cube is inside the cone, or if the cone is inside the cube, they intersect).

Comment: Should the solution yield a correct or approximate result?

Comment: so pos is a center of cube with edge ext, and base is a radius of a cone?

Comment: no base is the position of the center of the cone base.

Comment: @Stefan: I am searching for a correct result if possible

Comment: Then my first guess would be, to calculate (to some degree) the cut of the cone with the (infinite) faces of the cube and check if they are located on the actual faces. These cuts should be ellipses, parabolas or hyperbolas.

Comment: What if the entire cube is inside the cone, or vice versa? Does this count as an intersection, or do you only consider intersections of their surfaces?

Comment: See the note. It counts as an intersection.

Comment: Does the code need to find the intersection or is it sufficient to return a Boolean saying intersects or not. Because checking is pretty easy to do compared to finding the actual intersecting lines.

Comment: A boolean is sufficient

Comment: Uh, a bit too late. I posted a very long answer, maybe it can prove useful to you (more than 1 hour to write !)

Comment: I updated my answer, now I check whether the cone is inside the face (special case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## For the code

This answer will be slightly more general than your problem (I consider a box instead of a cube for example). Adapting to your case should be really straightforward.

### Some definitions

```
/*
    Here is the cone in cone space:

            +        ^
           /|\       |
          /*| \      | H
         /  |  \     |
        /       \    |
       +---------+   v

    * = alpha (angle from edge to axis)
*/
struct Cone // In cone space (important)
{
    double H;
    double alpha;
};

/*
    A 3d plane
      v
      ^----------+
      |          |
      |          |
      +----------> u
      P
*/
struct Plane
{
    double u;
    double v;
    Vector3D P;
};

// Now, a box.
// It is assumed that the values are coherent (that's only for this answer).
// On each plane, the coordinates are between 0 and 1 to be inside the face.
struct Box
{
    Plane faces[6];
};
```

### Line - cone intersection

Now, let's compute the intersection between a segment and our cone. Note that I will do calculations in cone space. Note also that I take the Z axis to be the vertical one. Changing it to the Y one is left as an exercise to the reader. The line is assumed to be in cone space. The segment direction is not normalized; instead, the segment is of the length of the direction vector, and starts at the point `P`:

```
/*
    The segment is points M where PM = P + t * dir, and 0 <= t <= 1
    For the cone, we have 0 <= Z <= cone.H
*/
bool intersect(Cone cone, Vector3D dir, Vector3D P)
{
    // Beware, indigest formulaes !
    double sqTA = tan(cone.alpha) * tan(cone.alpha);
    double A = dir.X * dir.X + dir.Y * dir.Y - dir.Z * dir.Z * sqTA;
    double B = 2 * P.X * dir.X +2 * P.Y * dir.Y - 2 * (cone.H - P.Z) * dir.Z * sqTA;
    double C = P.X * P.X + P.Y * P.Y - (cone.H - P.Z) * (cone.H - P.Z) * sqTA;

    // Now, we solve the polynom At² + Bt + C = 0
    double delta = B * B - 4 * A * C;
    if(delta < 0)
        return false; // No intersection between the cone and the line
    else if(A != 0)
    {
        // Check the two solutions (there might be only one, but that does not change a lot of things)
        double t1 = (-B + sqrt(delta)) / (2 * A);
        double z1 = P.Z + t1 * dir.Z;
        bool t1_intersect = (t1 >= 0 && t1 <= 1 && z1 >= 0 && z1 <= cone.H);

        double t2 = (-B - sqrt(delta)) / (2 * A);
        double z2 = P.Z + t2 * dir.Z;
        bool t2_intersect = (t2 >= 0 && t2 <= 1 && z2 >= 0 && z2 <= cone.H);

        return t1_intersect || t2_intersect;
    }
    else if(B != 0)
    {
        double t = -C / B;
        double z = P.Z + t * dir.Z;
        return t >= 0 && t <= 1 && z >= 0 && z <= cone.H;
    }
    else return C == 0;
}
```

### Rect - cone intersection

Now, we can check whether a rectangular part of a plan intersect the cone (this will be used to check whether a face of the cube intersects the cone). Still in cone space. The plan is passed in a way that will help us: 2 vectors and a point. The vectors are not normalized, to simplify the computations.

```
/*
    A point M in the plan 'rect' is defined by:
        M = rect.P + a * rect.u + b * rect.v, where (a, b) are in [0;1]²
*/
bool intersect(Cone cone, Plane rect)
{
    bool intersection = intersect(cone, rect.u, rect.P)
                     || intersect(cone, rect.u, rect.P + rect.v)
                     || intersect(cone, rect.v, rect.P)
                     || intersect(cone, rect.v, rect.P + rect.u);

    if(!intersection)
    {
        // It is possible that either the part of the plan lie
        // entirely in the cone, or the inverse. We need to check.
        Vector3D center = P + (u + v) / 2;

        // Is the face inside the cone (<=> center is inside the cone) ?
        if(center.Z >= 0 && center.Z <= cone.H)
        {
            double r = (H - center.Z) * tan(cone.alpha);
            if(center.X * center.X + center.Y * center.Y <= r)
                intersection = true;
        }

        // Is the cone inside the face (this one is more tricky) ?
        // It can be resolved by finding whether the axis of the cone crosses the face.
        // First, find the plane coefficient (descartes equation)
        Vector3D n = rect.u.crossProduct(rect.v);
        double d = -(rect.P.X * n.X + rect.P.Y * n.Y + rect.P.Z * n.Z);

        // Now, being in the face (ie, coordinates in (u, v) are between 0 and 1)
        // can be verified through scalar product
        if(n.Z != 0)
        {
            Vector3D M(0, 0, -d/n.Z);
            Vector3D MP = M - rect.P;
            if(MP.scalar(rect.u) >= 0
               || MP.scalar(rect.u) <= 1
               || MP.scalar(rect.v) >= 0
               || MP.scalar(rect.v) <= 1)
                intersection = true;
        }
    }
    return intersection;
}
```

### Box - cone intersection

Now, the final part : the whole cube:

```
bool intersect(Cone cone, Box box)
{
    return intersect(cone, box.faces[0])
        || intersect(cone, box.faces[1])
        || intersect(cone, box.faces[2])
        || intersect(cone, box.faces[3])
        || intersect(cone, box.faces[4])
        || intersect(cone, box.faces[5]);
}
```

## For the maths

Still in cone space, the cone equations are:

```
// 0 is the base, the vertex is at z = H
x² + y² = (H - z)² * tan²(alpha)
0 <= z <= H
```

Now, the parametric equation of a line in 3D is:

```
x = u + at
y = v + bt
z = w + ct
```

The direction vector is (a, b, c), and the point (u, v, w) lie on the line.

Now, let's put the equations together:

```
(u + at)² + (v + bt)² = (H - w - ct)² * tan²(alpha)
```

Then after developping and re-factorizing this equation, we get the following:

```
At² + Bt + C = 0
```

where A, B and C are shown in the first intersection function. Simply resolve this and check the boundary conditions on z and t.

Comment: For anyone : if you find a way to make the computations a little shorter, feel free to edit.

Comment: There is a mistake in your formula double B = 2 * P.X * dir.X +2 * P.Y * dir.Y - 2 * (cone.H - P.Z) * dir.Z * sqTA; It must be  + 2 * (cone.H - P.Z) * dir.Z * sqTA

Answer (score 5):

1. **imagine 2 infinite lines**

- axis of a cone
- line going through a point `P` (cube center for starters) which is perpendicular to cone axis.

Cone axis is known to you so that is easy, second line is defined as

```
    P+t*(perpendicular vector to cone axis)
```

This vector can be obtained by cross product of cone axis vector and vector perpendicular to your image (assuming Z axis). The `t` is scalar value parameter ...

2. **compute intersection of these 2 lines/axises**

if you do not know the equations derive them or google them. Let the intersection point be `Q`

3. **if intersection point `Q` does not lie inside cone**

(between vertex and base) then point `P` is not intersecting cone. From intersection equations you will obtain parameters `t1` and `t2`

- let `t1` be for `P` axis line
- and `t2` for cone axis line

if your axis line direction vector is also the cone length then intersection is inside cone if `t2 = <0,1>`

4. **if `P` is not inside triangle (cutted cone to plane generated by those 2 axises)**

this is also easy you know the position of `Q` inside cone (`t2`) so you know that the cone is in `P`-axis from `Q` to distance of `R*t2` where `R` is base radius of cone. So you can compute `|P-Q|` and check if it is `<=R*t2` or use directly `t1` (if `P` axis direction vector is unit).

if the distance is bigger then `R*t2` point `P` does not intersect cone.

5. **if #3 and #4 are positive then `P` intersects cone**

[image: cone]

- hope you dont mind here is your image with few things added for clarity

**[notes]**

Now the hard part there are edge cases when no vertex of cube is intersecting cone  but the cube itself is intersecting the cone anyway. This can occur when the `||P-Q|-R*t2| = <0,half cube size>` In this case you should check more points then just cube vertexes along the closest cube face.

**Another approach is:**

1. **create a transformation matrix for cone**

Where:

- its vertex as origin
- its axis as `+Z` axis
- and `XY` plane is parallel to its base

so any point is inside cone if

- `Z = <0,h>`
- `X*X + Y*Y <= (R*Z/h)^2` or `X*X + Y*Y <= (R*Z*tan(angle))^2`

2. **convert cube vertexes into cone space**

and check if any vertex is inside cone also you can check all cube edge lines with the conditions from #1 (algebraically) or use more points along cube faces as in previous method.

Chat discussion: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48756/discussion-between-spektre-and-joojaa

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier if you transform everything into cone space?

Comment: yes that is the second approach about ... but I am not familiar with your project ...so I do not know if you can handle transform matrices there. If yes then transformation is the best way as I see it

Comment: Why would transformation matrices be a problem? Its not like you can not implement the math in about a minute.

Comment: the usual (bad) reason is absence of knowledge but there are also relevant ones like on some implementations you do not have precise/fast enough FPU (or none at all) at disposal, also memory requirements can be pain in the ass ... but if you are coding for PC then there should not be a problem

Comment: Yes but in this case its a 4 by 4 matrix hardly any problem memory wise. In any case if you dont have a fpu then this is a big problem nonetheless. Tough to be honest I have implemented transformations with atmel cores without floating point support.

Comment: Mee too :) and also on 8bit Z80A but not everyone can do it so it is allways good to have options

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48756/discussion-between-spektre-and-joojaa)

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I made an efficient algorithm to test intersection between a cone and aabb for some rendering code. I recently needed this test for something I'm working on now, so I revisited it and made it even more efficient. I have spent way more time than I care to admit working on this problem and so I decided to spare you the misery and post the code. As such, this is AFAIK a completely unique solution and won't be found in a textbook (i.e. David Eberly's solution).

BIG EDIT: My previous algorithm handled most situations well enough that I didn't notice any problems - that is until I got a block of time large enough to test all situations rigorously. It had a small margin of error in one case, and a fairly large error margin in one other one when testing against the brute-force 6-planes approach. The segment-box test I was doing at the end couldn't account for all the possible weird situations where the expanding cone would penetrate the box. It looked good on my 2d and poorly-drawn-3d test cases, but failed in practice. My new idea is slightly more expensive, but it's bullet-proof.

The steps that the new version goes through are as follows:

1.) Early out if the apex is in the bounding box.

2.) Identify the faces that the cone can possibly touch (Max of 3) and add their vertices to an array.

3.) Project all of the vertices in the array into "cone-space".

4.) Early out if the projected vertices are inside the cone

5.) Do a circle-polygon-test against the vertex array and the radius of the cone to catch edge intersections with the polygon on border of the cone

```
bool Intersect(const Cone& pCone) const {
    Vector3 pFaceVerts[12];
    U32 uVertCount;
    int piClipSigns[3];
    U32 uClipCount = GetClipInfo(pCone.GetApex(), piClipSigns);

    switch (uClipCount) {
        // If the clip count is zero, the apex is fully contained in the box
        xcase 0: {
            return true;
        }
        // 1) Clips single face, 4 vertices, guaranteed to not touch any other faces
        xcase 1: {
            int iFacet = piClipSigns[0] != 0 ? 0 : (piClipSigns[1] != 0 ? 1 : 2);
            GetFacetVertices(iFacet, piClipSigns[iFacet], pFaceVerts);
            uVertCount = 4;
        }
        // 2) Clips an edge joining two candidate faces, 6 vertices
        // 3) Clips a vertex joining three candidate faces, 7 vertices
        xcase 2:
        acase 3: {
            uVertCount = 0;
            for (U32 iFacet = 0; iFacet < 3; iFacet++) {
                if (piClipSigns[iFacet] != 0) {
                    GetFacetVertices(iFacet, piClipSigns[iFacet], pFaceVerts + uVertCount);
                    uVertCount += 4;
                }
            }
            FixVertices(pFaceVerts, uVertCount);
        }
    }

    // Project vertices into cone-space
    F32 fConeRadiusSquared = Square(pCone.GetRadius());
    F32 pfLengthAlongAxis[6];
    bool bOutside = true;
    for (U32 i = 0; i < uVertCount; i++) {
        pfLengthAlongAxis[i] = Dot(pCone.GetAxis(), pFaceVerts[i] - pCone.GetApex());
        bOutside &= Clamp1(pfLengthAlongAxis[i], LargeEpsilon, pCone.GetHeight() - LargeEpsilon);
    }
    // Outside the cone axis length-wise
    if (bOutside) {
        return false;
    }
    for (U32 i = 0; i < uVertCount; i++) {
        Vector3 vPosOnAxis = pCone.GetApex() + pCone.GetAxis() * pfLengthAlongAxis[i];
        Vector3 vDirFromAxis = pFaceVerts[i] - vPosOnAxis;

        F32 fScale = (pCone.GetHeight() / pfLengthAlongAxis[i]);
        F32 x = fScale * Dot(vDirFromAxis, pCone.GetBaseRight());
        F32 y = fScale * Dot(vDirFromAxis, pCone.GetBaseUp());
        // Intersects if any projected points are inside the cone
        if (Square(x) + Square(y) <= fConeRadiusSquared) {
            return true;
        }
        pFaceVerts[i] = Vector2(x, y);
    }
    // Finally do a polygon circle intersection with circle center at origin
    return PolygonCircleIntersect(pFaceVerts, uVertCount, pCone.GetRadius());
}
```

GetClipInfo:

```
inline U32 GetClipInfo(const Vector3& P, int piClipSigns[3]) const {
    U32 N = 0;
    for (U32 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (P[i] < m_vMin[i]) {
            piClipSigns[i] = -1;
            N++;
        } else if (P[i] > m_vMax[i]) {
            piClipSigns[i] = +1;
            N++;
        } else {
            piClipSigns[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return N;
}
```

GetFacetVertices and FixVertices are slightly hacky at the moment, but they get the vertices on the face and fixup the vertices to be convex and ccw-ordered, respectively.

An alternative would be just to project all the vertices into cone-space without any fancy logic, but I need mine to be as fast as possible so I broke it down into several cases.

I tried various other approaches, notably a separating axis test between the cone axis and the box and used the largest separating axis to get the closest face to test with PolygonCircleIntersect, but I identified a failure case and so threw it out.

Answer (score 1):

Info: I don't know if this idea is already a patented intellectual property (in your region), or not, or how to find out, or whatever that means. I do this for fun. :)

But, here is the beef:

- **Step 1: Approximation:** For efficiency, treat both objects as spheres (use outer spheres). Calculate their **[distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)** (between their two center points), to find out if they are close enough to intersect at all. Quickly return false, if they can not possibly intersect (because their distance is greater than the sum of the radius of both spheres).
- **Step 2: Exact Computation:** This is the easy way to do it: Interpret the cone as a batch of 3-D pixels called **[voxels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel)** (or [legos](http://www.lego.com/en-us/createandshare)): Choose whatever resolution (granularity) you find acceptable (maybe 0.01). Create a vector pointing from (0,0,0) to any voxel point inside the volume of your cone (starting at the point you already named "vertex"). Return true, if the coordinate of that voxel exists inside your given cube. Repeat this for every voxel that you can compute for your cone object, based on the chosen granularity.
- **Step 3: If nothing matches**, return false.

Optimization: The function that determines if any given 3-D point is inside the cube might be optimizable, by considering the cube's inner sphere. Meaning, any given 3-D point is within the cube, if it is close enough to the center of the cube's inner sphere to be within that sphere. The fun begins, when you start filling the empty cube corners with additional spheres for more optimization (this is totally optional).

I'm sure there are further optimizations possible for step 2. However, the nice thing about this approach is that you can freely adjust the granularity, to fine tune between computation time and computation accuracy.

You can also create a solver that automatically reduces the granularity over multiple iterations. Meaning the accuracy increases over time (for better resolution).

Comment: Voxel approach is slow and when not properly implemented then even memory demanding. this would be fine for very complex shapes collision tests. but for simple meshes is far better to use transform matrix and simple 3 linear equation checks for coordinates instead ...

Comment: Well ... I don't claim anything else but that this is correct. It is an alternative answer. And, instead of providing a solution for just this problem, I decided to provide additional value. Feel free to use one of the simpler solutions that fits you best.

Comment: yep it is always a good to have more options but its also good to know in what cases is which one better