# What's the proper way to check a point is within a 3d cone

Tags: 3d, geometry, glm-math

So, this is embarrassing, looks like all of my high school math skills have rusted away.

I've laboriously put together some code that seems to work, but looking at it, I feel like I'm either doing this the roundabout way, or otherwise don't understand the math behind it.

```cpp
    glm::vec3 cameraDirection = glm::normalize(camera->lookat - camera->position);
    glm::vec3 cameraViewAxis = camera->position + (cameraDirection * (camera->farPlaneDistance) );          

    for(const auto & obj : scene->objects){
        glm::vec3 point = obj.position;

        glm::vec3 objDirection = glm::normalize(point - camera->position);
        float cosAlpha = glm::dot(objDirection, cameraDirection);

        float distance = glm::distance(camera->position, point);
        float distanceOnViewAxis = distance * cosAlpha;

        glm::vec3 pointOnViewAxis = camera->position + (cameraDirection * distanceOnViewAxis);

        float distanceFromViewAxis = glm::distance(pointOnViewAxis, point);
        float viewRadius = getViewRadius(distanceOnViewAxis); // based on FOV/aspect ratio

        if(distanceFromViewAxis < viewRadius){
            // might be visible
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the nagging feeling there's a better way of doing this, I only need `distanceOnViewAxis` and `distanceFromViewAxis`, which in trigonometric terms are the *adjacent* and *opposite* sides of the right triangle, I know the angles and the hypotenuse.

I've looked at a few similar questions, but they didn't really help me.

Comment: see [Detect if a cube and a cone intersect each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22066312/2521214)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more concise solution, using both dot product and cross product.

```cpp
bool is_in_cone(const glm::vec3& camera_pos, const glm::vec3& camera_direction, const glm::vec3& object_pos) {
    auto normalized_dir = glm::normalize(camera_direction);
    auto obj_vector = object_pos - camera_pos;
    auto dis_on_view_axis = glm::dot(obj_vector, normalized_dir);
    if (dis_on_view_axis < 0.0f) return false;
    return glm::length(glm::cross(obj_vector, normalized_dir)) <= getViewRadius(dis_on_view_axis);
}
```

I drew some graph to show the math behind this (note that in the graph I considered the limit of the cone's height, but you don't seem to need it)
[image: The equation in the bottom-right corner is for a point inside the cone to satisfy.]